# picker not work correctly inside flat list in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, picker

Inside each list item of flatlist, we have a Picker to choose value   But when we are changing the picker value it is changing and immediately refreshing for all another rows.
This is happening only when we are applying the Flatlist, but outside the flatlist it was fine.
Can anybody help us, how to solve the issue.

```
 import React from 'react';
import { Text, View,FlatList,Image,StyleSheet ,ScrollView, TextInput,TouchableOpacity,Alert 
 } from 'react-native';
import {  Picker ,Icon} from "native-base";
  var gradeInputs= [];
 var  hoursInput =[];
 var grades_list   =[
     {
  "course": "BIO-110",
  "TITLE": "أحياء عامة )1(",
     "hours":"2"
    }
   ,
          {
       "course": "CHEM-110",
      "TITLE": "كيمياء عامة )1(",
    "hours":"4"
 }
   ,
   {
   "course": "ELCS-100",
   "TITLE": "لغة انجليزية",
     "hours":"3"
 }
,
      {

     "course": "STAT-110",
       "TITLE": "احصاء عام )1(",
        "hours":"3"

     }

         ];
     export default class calculate_gpa extends React.Component {
       constructor(props)
       {

      super(props);
         this.state = {
     selected: "A+"
     };
    }
          onValueChange(value ) {
        this.setState({
            selected: value
    });
 }
 render( ) {
   return(  
      <View style={{flex:1}} >
     <ScrollView   >
         <Text style={{  fontSize:20,fontWeight: 'bold',
       fontFamily: "DroidKufiReqular",}}>{"\n"} أدخل الدرجة المتوقعة لكل مادة{"\n"}</Text>


     <FlatList
       data={ grades_list}
          maxHeight={400}
         renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
         <View    key={item.id}>
          <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center',
                 alignItems: 'center' ,
                marginTop:'7%', }}>


        </View >
     <View   style={{
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
         flexDirection:'row',
       alignItems:'center',
       marginTop:0,
        }}>
       <View style={{ width: '16.5%', alignItems:'center' , top:-20 }}>
       <Text style={{   textAlign: "center",}}>{item.course}</Text>  
        </View>
        <View  style={{   width: '20%', alignItems:'center',  top:-15   }}>
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: "DroidKufiRegular",
        }}>{item.TITLE}</Text> 
       </View>
            <View style={{  width: '20%', alignItems:'center' , top:-20,marginRight:0 }}>
               <Picker style={{borderStyle:'solid',height: 50, width: 120}}
          mode="dropdown"
          iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
          headerBackButtonText="Baaack!"
          selectedValue={this.state.selected}
          onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="A+" value="4.5" />
          <Picker.Item label="A" value="4" />
          <Picker.Item label="B+" value="3.5" />
          <Picker.Item label="B" value="3" />
          <Picker.Item label="C+" value="2" />
        </Picker>

      </View>
     <View style={{width: '16.5%', alignItems:'center', top:-15 }}>
      <Text style={{   textAlign: "center"}}>{item.hours}</Text>  
         </View> 
          </View>
        </View>
       }
       keyExtractor={item => item.id } 
       extraData={this.state}
     />
  <View style={{  justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',}}>
       <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}
       >
           <Text style={styles.loginText}>احتسب معدلك</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
       </ScrollView >
    </View>
       );

      }}

         const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonContainer: {
     height:60,
     flexDirection: 'row',
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
     marginBottom:15,
     width:250,
     borderRadius:30,
     marginTop:20,

   },
   loginButton: {
     backgroundColor: "#87dc9b",
   },
   loginText: {
     color: 'white',
       fontSize:20,
        fontFamily: "DroidKufiBold",
      },
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

that's becuase you are using a single value state.selected for all the items of the flatlist and therefore all items will have the same value. what you can do is to use an object in state where the keys are the indexes of flatlist items and the values are picker's selected values for that item. in this way all items will have different selected values.